# Google Sheet importxml tr td

Tags: xpath

wishing  to export the values in the red area into google sheets, i can't get the xpath corectly. Thanks a lot

**Edit**: I tried using this, and it s said that is empty

"`=IMPORTXML(A2,"//div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]","en_US")`"

https://subredditstats.com/r/funny
[image: td tr google sheets]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your approach is that the data you are trying to scrape is loaded dynamically, meaning it is not present in the source code of the page when you try to scrape it. To scrape dynamic content, you can use Google Apps Script and its built-in functions for scraping dynamic content.

Here's an example of how you can do it:

1 Go to Google Sheets and create a new sheet.

2 Go to Tools > Script editor.

3 In the Script editor, copy and paste the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://subredditstats.com/r/funny").getContentText();
  var doc = Xml.parse(html, true);
  var td = doc.getElementByXPath("//div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]");
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(td.toString());
}
```

4 Save the script and run the `myFunction` function.

5 Go back to the sheet and check cell A1 to see if the value has been imported.

Note: Keep in mind that some websites may block scraping, so this approach may not work in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

Check this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tZh43QVxJdOqTLXfWLQg8Z93S5jFZU6sl5G-I3Q2rrM/edit#gid=0

(it uses IMPORTRFOMWEB, the alternative to ImportXML)